# Insert list in database MySQLdb Python3.6

Tags: python-3.x, mysql-python, python-3.6

I am having a problem inserting a list in to a mysql database with the MySQLdb driver.

```
 import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "user", "password", "db")

c = db.cursor() 
cities = ["New York", "NY", 8400000]

sql = "INSERT INTO projecten.population(city, state, population) VALUES(?, ?, ?)", cities

try:
    c.execute(sql)
    db.commit()
except MySQLdb.OperationalError:
    print("error")
finally:
    db.close()
```

This is the error

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'tuple'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer

```
c.executemany("INSERT INTO projecten.population(city, state, population) VALUES(%s, %s, %s)", (cities))
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you would want to use string formatter with tuple -

```
>>> sql = "INSERT INTO projecten.population(city, state, population) VALUES('%s', '%s', '%s')" % tuple(cities)
>>> sql
"INSERT INTO projecten.population(city, state, population) VALUES('New York', 'NY', '8400000')"
```

Comment: But using % is not safe with sql injections

Comment: Valid point. Can you try cur.execute("INSERT INTO projecten.population(city, state, population) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", (cities,)) Refer - http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#some-examples

Comment: You can only use (cities,) when the variable contains one value. If the variable contains more than one value you use (cities).

Answer (score 0):

The SQL statement should be correctly passed with values.

```
import MySQLdb
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "user", "password", "db")
c = db.cursor() 
cities = ["New York", "NY", 8400000]
sql = "INSERT INTO projecten.population(city, state, population) VALUES({0}, {1}, {2})".format(*cities)
try:
    c.execute(sql)
    db.commit()
except MySQLdb.OperationalError:
    print("error")
finally:
    db.close()
```